# Do i.i.d. sums concentrate any faster than martingales?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, measure-concentration, martingales

Suppose $X_1,X_2, \ldots, X_N \in \mathbb R^d$ are random variables with each $\|X_n\|_2 \le 1/2$ (this choice of the constant simplifies later formulae).

The simplest concentration inequality I know only applies in the case $d=1$ and only when $X_1,X_2, \ldots, X_N$ are i.i.d. The Hoeffding Lemma gives for each $\epsilon >0$ the bound

$$P(|X_1 + \ldots + X_N| \ge \epsilon) \le \exp\left (-\frac{2\epsilon^2}{N} \right).\tag{1}$$

On the other end of the spectrum are results that work under the weaker assumption that $X_1,X_2, \ldots, X_N$ is a martingale, and work for any $d \in \mathbb N$, or indeed for infinite dimensional Banach spaces provided some variant of the parallelogram is satisfied. For example [Theorem 3.5 of this paper of Pinelis](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aop/1176988477) leads to the following variant of the Azuma-Hoeffding inequality.

$$P(\|X_1 + \ldots + X_n\|_2 \ge \epsilon \text{ for some }n\le N) \le \exp\left (-\frac{\epsilon^2}{2N} \right).\tag{2}$$

The exponent is the same as the scalar Azuma Hoeffding.
Notice the $2$ is now downstairs rather than upstairs like before.

If we are only dealing with i.i.d scalars and only interested in the final element, we should use $(1)$ because it gives a better bound. If we are dealing with either vectors, martingales, or want a uniform inequality we better use $(2)$ instead.

My problem is between the two extremes. I am dealing with a sequence of i.i.d vectors in $\mathbb R^d$ and I am interested in a uniform bound. I wonder does there exist an appropriate middle-ground between these two results? Perhaps combining the $-2\epsilon^2/N$ of the first with the uniform nature of the second, at the expense of only applying to i.i.d sequences as opposed to martingales.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other than the presence of an extra factor $D$ or $D^2$, depending on the context, the coefficients in the bounds for martingales in $(2,D)$-smooth spaces in the paper you cite are exactly the same as the ones for sums of independent real-valued random variables. There is no gap in this sense.

Also, you are citing Hoeffding's inequality incorrectly: the restriction on the $X_n$'s is of course in terms of the $\infty$-norm, rather than in terms of the $2$-norm.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! Clearly I have been staring at these things for too long to realize the generalsiation of $-1/2 \le X_n \le 1/2$ is not in fact $\|X_n\| \le 1$ but $\|X_n\| \le 1/2$.

Comment: To write out the restriction in full, should it be $\sup\{\|X(x)\|_2: x \in \Omega\} \le 1/2$ where $\Omega$ is the probability space and $\|\cdot\|_2$ is the $2$-norm on $\mathbb R^d$?

Comment: @Daron : Concerning your latest comment: that is right.

Comment: I wonder could you provide any reference for the following type of Martingale problem? Suppose $f_0,f_1,f_2,\ldots$ is an (infinite) martingale starting at $f_0=0$ and we want to bound the chance that after some big $N \in \mathbb N$ all the normalised values $\|\frac{f_n}{n}\|$ are less than $1$ say. We can of course take the exponential bound from one of your theorems, do a union bound, and estimate that by integrating the exponential. But that seems a pretty crude way to go about things. Are there any more sophisticated techniques available?

Comment: Doing the union bound gives something like $C e^{-cN}$ for some constants $C,c>0$. I tried to be clever and instead force some subsequence of $\|f_n\|/n$ to be less than $1/2$ say because this forces the elements in between to be less than $1$. That leads to integrating something like $\exp(ab^x)$ and I can only get a bound like $C e^{-cN}/N$. I can write this out as a full question if you like?

Comment: @Daron : Yes, I think it is always best, in more ways than one, to ask additional questions separately.

Comment: Thanks. The new question can be found here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/332756/for-a-martingale-f-0-f-1-ldots-how-can-we-bound-p-frac1n-f-n-le-1